# Checking new mails of Gmail account through python

Tags: python, email, gmail, python-2.x, poplib

I'm using this code to check for new mails with a 10 seconds delay.

```
import poplib
from email import parser
import time

def seeit(): 
    pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com')
    pop_conn.user('xxx')
    pop_conn.pass_('xx')
    #Get messages from server:
    messages = [pop_conn.retr(i) for i in range(1, len(pop_conn.list()[1]) + 1)]
    # Concat message pieces:a
    messages = ["\n".join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]
    #Parse message intom an email object:
    messages = [parser.Parser().parsestr(mssg) for mssg in messages]
    for message in messages:
        print message['subject']
    pop_conn.quit()


starttime=time.time()

while True:
    k=10.0
    print "tick"
    seeit()
    time.sleep(k - ((time.time() - starttime) % k))
```

How can i retrieve the email body without headers?

Comment: Do you get the messages without any errors?

Comment: yes. currently it displays the 'subject'

Comment: Can you print message bodies? You want to print message bodies without subjects? Right?

Comment: actually i want to print both the subject and the body.

Comment: The code you posted does not run.  Please [edit] your question to provide runnable code.  Indentation is significant in Python, so you will want to make sure the indentation in your question matches what you actually run.  Usually, copy/paste the code, select the pasted block, and press ctrl-K to have it properly formatted for Stack Overflow.  There will be detailed Markdown help on the right while you are editing.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the method `get_payload()` method from the `email` package.

Try this after you get the messages from server:

```
import email

...
messages = [pop_conn.retr(i) for i in range(1, len(pop_conn.list()[1]) + 1)]
...

for i in messages:
    mssg = email.message_from_string(i)
    print(mssg.get_payload())
```

Comment: i got an error 'message_from_string' is not defined'

Comment: Did you import email by using `import email`?